# Why does scalatest mix up the output?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I run my scalatest from sbt, and the output gets mixed up - scalatest prints all the test run, and comments to them, and somewhere in the middle it prints the statistics:

```
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/platon/Tor/scala-dojo-02/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[info] FunsWithListsTests:
[info] - should return list of labels
[info] - should return the average rating of games belonging to Zenga
[info] - should return the total ratings of all games
[info] - should return the total ratings of EA games *** FAILED ***
[info]   0 did not equal 170 (FunsWithListsTests.scala:35)
[error] Failed: : Total 8, Failed 5, Errors 0, Passed 3, Skipped 0
[info] - should increase all games rating by 10 *** FAILED ***
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     dojo.FunsWithListsTests
[info]   List() did not equal List(Game(Activision,40), Game(Zenga,70), Game(Zenga,20), Game(EA,70), Game(EA,120)) (FunsWithListsTests.scala:40)
[info] - should decrease all Zenga games rating by 10 *** FAILED ***
[info]   List() did not equal List(Game(Activision,30), Game(Zenga,50), Game(Zenga,0), Game(EA,60), Game(EA,110)) (FunsWithListsTests.scala:45)
[info] - should create function to find Activision games *** FAILED ***
[info]   List(Game(Activision,30), Game(Zenga,60), Game(Zenga,10), Game(EA,60), Game(EA,110)) did not equal List(Game(Activision,30)) (FunsWithListsTests.scala:50)
[info] - should return a List of tuples consisting of game label and game *** FAILED ***
[info]   List() did not equal List((ACTIVISION,Game(Activision,30)), (ZENGA,Game(Zenga,60)), (ZENGA,Game(Zenga,10)), (EA,Game(EA,60)), (EA,Game(EA,110))) (FunsWithListsTests.scala:56)
[error] {file:/home/platon/Tor/scala-dojo-02/}default-940f03/test:test: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 20, 2012 9:27:13 AM
```

It seems that if I would accumulate a great number of tests, searching for those stats and failed tests would become a pain.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example to reproduce this? I wasn't able to produce an output like this.

Comment: @drexin - https://github.com/Rogach/scala_dojo

Comment: @drexin - not exactly minimal, but this is where I discovered it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an idea why this happens, sorry. Maybe you should write to the scalatest mailing list.

Comment: Posted to scalatest google group.

Comment: @Rogach   Your github link is dead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me the reason for that is that SBT by default executes the tests in parallel, the same way maven-surefire-plugin does.

As it is explained in ScalaTest wiki, this can be solved by:

Disable Parallel Execution of Tests
By default, sbt runs all tasks in parallel. Because each test is mapped to a task, tests are also run in parallel by default. To disable parallel execution of tests:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue and solved it by saving logs into separate files. Not ideal, but good for CI, especially in case of long-running integration tests. How I did it:

1. Create a special directory for logs (for example, at the end of build.sbt):

   ```
   lazy val logDirectory = taskKey[File]("A directory for logs")
   logDirectory := {
     val r = target.value / "logs"
     IO.createDirectory(r)
     r
   }
   ```
2. [Optionally] Specify a file for a summary information in a project:

   ```
   testOptions in test += Tests.Argument(
     TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-fW", (logDirectory.value / "summary.log").toString
   )
   ```

   [W](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt) disables colors
3. Create a group for each test. Each group must run a test in a forked JVM with special arguments:

   ```
   testGrouping in test := testGrouping.value.flatMap { group =>
     group.tests.map { suite =>
       val fileName = {
         // foo.bar.baz.TestSuite -> f.b.b.TestSuite
         val parts = suite.name.split('.')
         (parts.init.map(_.substring(0, 1)) :+ parts.last).mkString(".")
       }

       val forkOptions = ForkOptions(
         bootJars = Nil,
         javaHome = javaHome.value,
         connectInput = connectInput.value,
         outputStrategy = outputStrategy.value,
         runJVMOptions = javaOptions.value ++ Seq(
           "-Dour.logging.appender=FILE",
           s"-Dour.logging.dir=${logDirectory.value / fileName}"
         ),
         workingDirectory = Some(baseDirectory.value),
         envVars = envVars.value
       )

       group.copy(
         name = suite.name,
         runPolicy = Tests.SubProcess(forkOptions),
         tests = Seq(suite)
       )
     }
   }
   ```

   Note, we can tell the logback, where we save our logs through **our.logging.appender** and **our.logging.dir**
4. Create a configuration for logging (test/resources/logback-test.xml):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
       <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
           <target>System.out</target>
           <encoder>
               <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{26} - %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
       </appender>

       <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
           <file>${our.logging.dir}/test.log</file>
           <append>false</append>
           <encoder>
               <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{26} - %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
       </appender>

       <root level="TRACE">
           <appender-ref ref="${our.logging.appender}"/>
       </root>
   </configuration>
   ```

That's all.