# How can I run tests in parallel but get neatly ordered test output?

Tags: junit, sbt, parallel-testing

I'm using sbt and JUnit to run tests for a large Scala project. I'm [forking multiple JVMs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Forking.html) for tests, and defining how tests should be grouped in the JVMs using `testGrouping in Test`.

The tests are running in parallel, but their output is interleaved, making it hard to read through. I have set `logBuffered in Test := true`, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Here's a snippet from my `settings`:

```scala
parallelExecution in Test := true,
testForkedParallel in Test := false,
concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(Tags.limit(Tags.ForkedTestGroup, 8)),

testGrouping in Test := (definedTests in Test, javaOptions in Test) map groupBySuite,
testGrouping in Test := {
  val original: Seq[Tests.Group] = (testGrouping in Test).value

  original.map { group =>
    val forkOptions = ForkOptions(
      bootJars = Nil,
      javaHome = javaHome.value,
      connectInput = connectInput.value,
      outputStrategy = outputStrategy.value,
      runJVMOptions = (javaOptions in Test).value,
      workingDirectory = Some(baseDirectory.value),
      envVars = envVars.value
    )

    group.copy(runPolicy = Tests.SubProcess(forkOptions))
  }
},
logBuffered in Test := true,
```

How can I keep my tests running in parallel, but have the output somehow be buffered and displayed in order so that it is readable? Is there perhaps some setting I need to feed to `outputStrategy` in the forked JVM options?

There is [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782264/why-scalatest-mixes-up-the-output), but I am looking to keep my tests running in parallel.

Answer (score -2):

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html

`parallelExecution in Test` controls whether tests are mapped to separate tasks. To restrict the number of concurrently executing tests in all projects, use:

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
```