# disable parallelExecution in a scala gradle project

Tags: eclipse, scala, gradle, scalatest, scala-ide

I am learning scala in eclipse scala ide and the project is build using gradle. Just wondering, how to disable parallelExecution of scala tests.

Solution described in below stackoverflow questions is using sbt build.

[How to run subprojects tests (including setup methods) sequentially when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895063/how-to-run-subprojects-tests-including-setup-methods-sequentially-when-testing/27690751#27690751)

[How to turn off parallel execution of tests for multi-project builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899723/how-to-turn-off-parallel-execution-of-tests-for-multi-project-builds)

[Why does scalatest mix up the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782264/why-does-scalatest-mix-up-the-output)

**Note : I am running my test in scala ide using ide support (Run as Scala Test) .**

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue ?